# Base 10 to any base from 2-9

Tags: python

Hello I’m having some trouble with my code,

```
def bconver(n,b):
for i in range(n):
    x = b ** i
```

I’m trying to change a number from base 10 to any base from 2-9. I’m trying to do this without x=123456789abcdef or any libraries. An example of this would be 14 inputted as n and 2 as b , which would output 1110. 
The part I need the most help is, how do I get b to the power of all the values in the range of n(if I don’t need this please correct me)

I know these prices of code will be in the program, but don’t know how it will be implemented in.

```
n//x ,n%x
```

Also ps sorry if the question is not formatted correctly I’m using a mobile device.

Comment: Must be the third question for this today. Who gave you that homework?

Comment: Really third one, could u share the links please. Like to see if the same class

Comment: How about you scroll down on your own after you put a a lot of effort in solving the homework?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function to do this (sort of).

```
def bconver(n,b):
    return int(n,b)
```

int() has two value, number and base, so bconver(14, 2) would return 14 in base 2 (1110).

Does that help?

Comment: What does int do. Like it automatically does base conversions